# Open the Phone (Call) with a button and a Text field/View (iPhone)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, phone-number, phone-call

Would this be possible?

The app will have a button and a Text Field or a Text View.

The user types in the phone number in the Text Field or Text View. when the user is done the user presses the button which will open the Phone button and place the call to the number.

How would I do this? If possible please provide some code! :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at this code, This should work fine!

```
-(IBAction)newuser:(id)sender;
{
    NSString *URLString = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:textfield.text];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
}
```

Comment: Note that the RFC states a telephone URL starts with `tel:` and not `tel://`

Answer (score 2):

You can format a phone number as a `tel://` URL. So, if you have a text field (`MyTextField` for our purposes here):

```
NSString *URLString = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:MyTextField.text];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
```

Comment: Note that the RFC states a telephone URL starts with `tel:` and not `tel://`

Comment: In second line of your code url is nil when we assign urlstring to url. Plz help                                                                                                                                                                                   NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];                                           result is nil

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone supports the tel: URI scheme, as defined by [RFC 3966](http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=3966). So a simple example that would ask that the phone call the number '12345' would be:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:12345"]];
```

That should cause the device to switch over to the normal Phone application and dial the number. You'll want to validate the text field to check for illegal entries; the spec actually allows quite a few characters (see the formal grammar on page 5), but as a first test you might want to remove anything that isn't a number.

Comment: Note that the RFC states a telephone URL starts with `tel:` and not `tel://`